How to Reopen VLC videos on KDE restart?
Is there any method (or plugin) to make KDE's session resume reopen any videos I had open with VLC? And ideally at the same time in the paused video.
(I know VLC is supposed to do this, but it rarely remembers for me and I don't know why. But that is a different issue.)
UPDATE: after doing a lot of searching, I could not find an answer so I wrote a solution myself. I'm writing a system script and plug-in to do this. Here's the basic version.
https://github.com/cdobrich/kde-vlc-session-manager

Please add an answer with details about how to use your script
